# How to get select2 data from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I don't know what the title should be, hehe
but anyone know how to get select2 data from ajax response

here my code:

```
function selectData(){
    $('#select-data').select2({
    tags: true,
    data: arr_data,
});
}


var arr_data = dataArr();

function dataArr(){
  $.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL + 'position/allowance_get',
    dataType: 'json',
    });

}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, haha

the response like this

```
[{"allowance_id":"1","position_id":"1","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Kendaraan","allowance_value":"1000000"
},{"allowance_id":"10","position_id":"4","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Istri Tua","allowance_value":"1000000"
},{"allowance_id":"11","position_id":"4","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Istri Muda","allowance_value":"1000000"
},{"allowance_id":"29","position_id":"10","allowance_name":"Allowance Lipstic","allowance_value":"500000"
},{"allowance_id":"30","position_id":"10","allowance_name":"Allowance Powder","allowance_value":"600000"
},{"allowance_id":"31","position_id":"10","allowance_name":"Allowance Dalaman","allowance_value":"1000000"
},{"allowance_id":"32","position_id":"11","allowance_name":"Allowance Tunjangan","allowance_value":"20000000"
},{"allowance_id":"33","position_id":"11","allowance_name":"Allowance Kendaraan","allowance_value":"5000000"
},{"allowance_id":"34","position_id":"12","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Keluarga","allowance_value":"1000000"
},{"allowance_id":"35","position_id":"12","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Transportasi","allowance_value"
:"2000000"},{"allowance_id":"36","position_id":"12","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Hari Raya","allowance_value"
:"10000000"},{"allowance_id":"39","position_id":"13","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Makan","allowance_value"
:"2000000"},{"allowance_id":"40","position_id":"13","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Minum","allowance_value"
:"400000"},{"allowance_id":"41","position_id":"15","allowance_name":"Tunjangan Dinas","allowance_value"
:"23234343434"}]
```

I want to get the allowance_id and allowance_name

Comment: `var arr_data = dataArr();` - That won't really work since your ajax call in that function is asynchronous. (the function returns something before the ajax call is finished). And I don't see that you have any `return` in your `dataArary()`-function or even a `complete`-handler on your ajax call.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't get it, can you give me an example sir, please

Comment: You can [read this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/) for an explanation about sync and async in JS. You can also read about the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)-method in jQuerys documentation to get a better understanding on how to use it.

Comment: your ajax call is incomplete, function must return array to be used further. More information for ajax call can be seen here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with below code flow

```
var arr_data = [];

function selectData(){
    $('#select-data').select2({
      tags: true,
      data: arr_data,
    });
}

function dataArr(){
  $.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL + 'position/allowance_get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
      var tempObj = {};
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        tempObj = {"id":data[i].allowance_id,"text":data[i].allowance_name};
        arr_data.push(tempObj);
      }
      selectData();

    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude you are my hero